# How to center Stack View inside Container View

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have bunch of UI components contain inside stack view. I want that stack view to center horizontally and vertically in it's parent view which is a Container View. But "Horizontal Center" and "Vertical Center" options aren't available to set. How to achieve this ?

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
This is the result I get when "Horizontally in Container" and "Vertically in Container" are set.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that exactly what "Horizontally in Container" and "Vertically in Container" are?

Comment: After setting those two constraints, you also need to set the height and width constraint.

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. Still new to swift. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check both `Horizontally in Container` and `Vertically in Container`, it makes the stackView center inside the container, but if its not center of screen you might adjust the Container View constraints in previous view Controller, if your container is inside a scrollView you might have to uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in your view controller, if it doesn't help please post a picture of your simulator preview :)